# Is this function considered terminated?

Tags: c, function, procedures

Suppose the code goes like this

```
void b()
{
...
}
void c()
{
    b();
}
```

is c considered terminated after the call to b but b has not yet terminated?

Comment: c() will be terminated after b() is terminated - at least in the general concept you are talking about

Comment: A compiler might optimize your code so it terminates `c()` before `b()`, but you shouldn't think in optimized code.

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt: What kind of optimization will return calling function, before the return from called function?

Comment: @CancerSoftware [Tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail-call_optimization)

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt: Hats off to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify using debug messages:

```
void b()
{
    cout << "b()" << endl;
}
void c()
{
    b();
    cout << "ended c()" << endl;
}
```

So, the `ended c()` appears **after** `b()` message.

Answer (score 0):

No, `c()` is not supposed to be terminated before `b()` is terminated in general case.